How to make Chrome browser > storage > Cookies store cookies from the node express server in localStorage using reactJs
I get this error in the Chrome brower network, from the server whenever the user tries to update their information. (I have protected the update route so that only the logged in user to change their information)
{"success":false,"statusCode":401,"message":"Not authorized, No token"}
The user has logged in but the browser cannot store the token in its cookies in the storage

This is the expressJs code protecting the routes (Backend Code)

authMiddleware.js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import User from "../modules/user.module.js";
import { errorHandler } from "../utils/errorHandler.js";

const protect = async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  token = req.cookies.jwt; //cookie parser in action

  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.jwt_secret);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.userId).select("-password");
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      next(errorHandler(401, "Not authorized, Invalid token"));
    }
  } else {
    next(errorHandler(401, "Not authorized, No token"));
  }
};

export { protect };


These are the routers some of which are protected using jsonwebtoken (Backend Code)

user.routes.js
import express from "express";
import {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  logoutUser,
  userProfile,
  updateUser,
} from "../controllers/user.controller.js";
import { protect } from "../middleware/authMiddleware.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/sign-up", registerUser);
router.post("/sign-in", loginUser);
router.post("/sign-out", logoutUser);
router.get("/profile", protect, userProfile);
router.put("/profile", protect, updateUser);

export default router;


This is how I fetch the data from backend and manages the state using Redux

redux/store/store.js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from "../slices/authSlice";
import { apiSlice } from "../slices/apiSlice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  devTools: true,
});

export default store;

redux/slices/apiSlice.js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "" });

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ["User"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});


slices/authSlice.js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  userInfo: localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
    : null,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCredentials: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo = action.payload;
      localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(action.payload));
    },
    logout: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo = null;
      localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
    },
  },
});

export const { setCredentials, logout } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;

slices/usersApiSlice.js
import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice";
import { api } from "../../api";

export const usersApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${api}/sign-in`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),

    register: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${api}/sign-up`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
    logout: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: `${api}/sign-out`,
        method: "POST",
      }),
    }),
    updateUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${api}/profile`,
        method: "PUT",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useLoginMutation,
  useLogoutMutation,
  useRegisterMutation,
  useUpdateUserMutation,
} = usersApiSlice;

Postman and Insomnia generates and stores cookies and a user can change their particulars once they log in or sign up. However, when I use the api on the browser, the browser fails to capture the token created when a user signs up or logs in. and the user cannot edit or change their profile.
Anyone with the solution I will appreciate. I am using Chrome browser for development. But I have tried with other different browsers but the problem persists.
